# How to combine multiple arrays with identical keys into a single array?

Tags: php, arrays, merge, multidimensional-array

I am new to php. I need some help.
I had a array as

```
Array ( [_] => Array ( [0] => [1] => )
        [123_] => Array ( [0] => 123 [1] => ) 
        [1234_] => Array ( [0] => 1234 [1] => )
      )
Array ( [_] => Array ( [0] => [1] => )
        [12345_] => Array ( [0] => 12345 [1] => ) 
        [1234_] => Array ( [0] => 1234 [1] => )
      )
```

so..whats my problem is i want an array with  all these keys and values as

```
Array ( [_] => Array ( [0] => [1] => )
        [123_] => Array ( [0] => 123 [1] => ) 
        [1234_] => Array ( [0] => 1234 [1] => )
        [_] => Array ( [0] => [1] => )
        [12345_] => Array ( [0] => 12345 [1] => ) 
        [1234_] => Array ( [0] => 1234 [1] => )
  )
```

there would be duplicate keys and values.. but I want all of them as  a array.. any help plz..

Comment: please use `print_r`, `var_dump` or better yet `var_export` when providing variable dumps.

Comment: that's impossible. when you call "123_" element, which one it should be?

Comment: What do you use the array for? What does it represent? Do you want to detect duplicates and merge these or do you want to prevent duplicates by giving them unique keys?

Comment: You practically give the answer yourself: "there woul be duplicate keys and values". If it's duplicate it wouldn't be a key anymore, would it?

Comment: oh..i am sorry.i didnt observe that and i just given that as example. neglect that.there is no matter of same keys..actually thats a resultset i got through looping a query..but there are same values with different keys..can u explain how can i get all these as a single array..thx in advance.

Answer (score 7):

That is **not** possible. A PHP array cannot have two identical keys.

Comment: i am sorry. i changed the query. so that i got different keys. but the values might be equal some time. can we form that in a single array.   Array ( [_] => Array ( [0] => [1] => ) 
        [123_aug] => Array ( [0] => 123 [1] => )  
        [1234_aug] => Array ( [0] => 1234 [1] => ) 
      ) 
Array ( [_] => Array ( [0] => [1] => ) 
        [12345_aug] => Array ( [0] => 123 [1] => )  
        [123456_aug] => Array ( [0] => 1234 [1] => ) 
      ) 
how can  ii form this..

Comment: @bsrreddy: You sill have the key `_` common in both the arrays.

Comment: oh..i am sorry.i didnt observe that and i just given that as example. neglect that.there is no matter of same keys..actually thats a resultset i got through looping a query..hope u understand .

Answer (score 1):

As the others said, it's impossible to have a single array with duplicate keys. But you can build an array of array :

```
<?php
$arr1 = array( '_' => Array ( '0' => '', '1' => ''),
             '123_' => Array ( '0' => 123, '1' => ''), 
             '1234_' => Array ( '0' => 1234, '1' => '')
);
$arr2 = array ( '_' => Array ( '0' => '', '1' => ''),
               '12345_' => Array ( '0' => 12345, '1' => ''), 
               '1234_' => Array ( '0' => 1234, '1' => '')
);
$result = array();
foreach( $arr1 as $key => $val) {
  $result[] = array('key'=>$key, 'value'=>$val);
}
foreach( $arr2 as $key => $val) {
  $result[] = array('key'=>$key, 'value'=>$val);
}
print_r($result);
?>
```

Ouput:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => _
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>
                    [1] =>
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key] => 123_
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 123
                    [1] =>
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [key] => 1234_
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1234
                    [1] =>
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [key] => _
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>
                    [1] =>
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [key] => 12345_
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12345
                    [1] =>
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [key] => 1234_
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1234
                    [1] =>
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at PHP's [`array_merge()`-function](http://php.net/array_merge).

Comment: those are not different arrays to use merge function..those are again in a array. so i want that to be a single array..thx for ur reply